# can a top/bottom feed style sub-panel be fed from back of panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I have an Eaton main lug load center that is listed as top or bottom feed. I had to run EMT through a wall to the back of the panel.

Is it legal to use a knockout in the back of the panel (top part of panel just to right or left of center in the back) to feed the wire through?

It is #6 thhn stranded wire. It would have the appropriate emt to box fitting.

I cannot find any information on this.  I only find examples of either the wires fed through the sides of the panel or the top or bottom.  There is plenty of room but the wires would be making a 90 degree bend as they came into the back of the box to get to the main lugs which are below the knockout.

The alternative would be to put a junction box above the load center and come through the back of it and then down into the top of the load center.

The box is a 125amp eaton ch box.

thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed a panel from the back but you still need a hub or clamp to protect the wiring coming into the box. Try to do it as low as possible so you have enough bending radius most modern boxes have plenty of room. .

Answer (score 3):

The panel has knockouts all over the place.  They don't care which knockout you use.

"Top or bottom feed" doesn't pertain to where on the panel *the EMT enters*; it pertains to **where on the busbars** you attach the *wires*.

The very fact that you have a choice of two sets of lugs (top and bottom), implies this is a main-lug panel (not main-breaker) and it either has

- symmetrical screws (so the whole busbar assembly can be unbolted and installed upside-down) or
- has "thru lugs" (a second set of lugs on the bottom of the buses) is intended for if you want to continue power to a second subpanel.

Answer (score -1):

The power feed is fine from back as long as the knockout isn't using symmetrical knockouts... if you cut ur own hole + not use one of the step dwn sizes, it's to code.   =)

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.